# visual studio code don't show where is the error

Tags: flutter

hello any flutter project don't show where the error happen it does not track errors. It does not track the location of the error so that I can click on it and go to the error, like a simple example of that

[vs code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyYpn.png)

the android studio detect and show where error and it is clickable

[android studio error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Kq8.png)

i reset my vscode setting and the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is a bit different than Android Studio. To track where is the error, you need to click on the Problems tab. On the problems tab, you can see all warnings, and errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I will suggest using [Error Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) for VS-code which will show error while writing code.

And for android studio try [InlineError](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17302-inlineerror).
Make sure to install flutter extension as well.

Comment: thanks for your help i actually used to vscode but idk what happened

Comment: Things are supposed to work fine if you've installed extentions